# Style background of icon

Tags: html, css

I want to style the background of an icon. My code gives me an egg-shape but vertical, and I want the egg-shape to be horizontal. Also that the "egg" covers my icon in full. Is that possible?

Updated Fiddle... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/k48ue79y/18/)

HTML:

```
<div class="car">
<div class="pull-left"> <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.car .fa-calculator {
    color:black;
    font-size:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:80%
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D - Sorry, fa classes updated. Not sure why Fiddle doesnt show demo, I guess cause font-awesome.css is missing... :(

Comment: Why don't you add it...

Comment: @Paulie_D - just fingured it out and added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS it will work

```
.car .pull-left i {
    color:black;
    font-size:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:80%;
    height:100px;
    width:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
.car .fa-calculator {
    color:black;
    font-size:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:block;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:.5em;
    width:1.6em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the egg-shape to be horizontal. Also that the "egg" covers my icon in full.

For an 'egg' shape the element has to be wider than it is tall (if we are to use border-radius).

So setting uneven padding would seem to be an option.

```css
.car .fa-calculator {
    color:black;
 font-size:100px;
 background-color:#FF0000;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding: .2em .4em; /* adjust as required */
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="car">
<div class="pull-left"> <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></div>
</div>
```